# Form Goes Crazy After Linking CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a form I'm working on and I'm trying to align all my fields to make it look presentable and the page goes crazy when I link a css page to it.  I don't understand why my textareas aren't floating to the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<!--<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="reporter.css" TYPE="text/css">-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendarDateInput.js"></script>
<title>Downtime Reporting</title>
    </head>
<body>
<form action = "addissue.php" METHOD = "POST">
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/jasoncalendar.htm
<script>DateInput('orderdate', true, 'DD-MON-YYYY')</script>

Please select the application affected:
<select name = "application">
<option value = "Default1">Default2</option>
<option value = "2">2</option>
</select><br />
Start Time:  <input type = "text" name = "start" /><br />
End Time:  <input type = "text" name = "end" /><br />
Service Level Affecting? <input type = "radio" name = "sla" value = "Yes" />Yes
                         <input type = "radio" name = "sla" value = "No" />No<br />
System State:
<select name = "state">
<option value = "down">Down</option>
<option value = "degradated">Degradated</option>
<option value = "feature">Feature Broken</option>
</select><br />
Issue Description: 
<textarea name = "issuedesc"rows = "5" cols = "90">Enter Issue Description Here.</textarea><br />
Resolution Description:
<textarea name = "resdesc" rows = "5" cols = "90">Enter Resolution Description Here.</textarea><br />
Group Issue Is Assigned To:
<select name = "group">
<option value = "default1">default1</option>
<option value = "2">2</option>
</select><br />
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

My css file just consists of this right now.

```
textarea{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: In your code above, you have `<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="reporter.css" TYPE="text/css">` wrapped in a comment. Is the `textarea` CSS defined in this file? If it is, that's why the `float:right` isn't working, because it's not loading the CSS file in which it's contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried out your code and if by "goes crazy" you means your textareas float to the right and stack against each other then this is expected.

Have you considered just using a simple table to layout your form like so?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="myInput">My input: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maybe try laying this out with a `table`. Will make life much easier.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="aligh: right;">Caption</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="aligh: right;">Longer Caption</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need tables, you just have to understand CSS floating.  Change your `<br />` elements after the textareas to `<br style="clear:both" />` and it may look more like what you expected.